# Faster way of doing multiple checks on one dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a better way to rewrite the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, 'Testing #1' 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL && Column3='Value'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, 'Testing #2'
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column3 IS NULL && Column2='Test Value'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT Column1, 'Testing #3'
FROM MyTable
Where ....
```

In have about 35 union all statements that all query the same table. I was wondering if there's an easier/faster way to do things.

Comment: use a case statement...

Comment: how many columns are we testing here or is it just columns 2 & 3?

Comment: @RhianA, There are six columns

Comment: @MitchWheat, Case statement doesn't work for multiple matching criteria for one row. (See my comment below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can rewrite it with case statements like this

```
SELECT Column1,
CASE WHEN Column2 IS NOT NULL AND Column3='Value' THEN 'Testing #1'
     WHEN Column3 IS NULL AND Column2='Test Value' THEN 'Testing #2'
     ELSE 'Testing #3' END as customcol
FROM MyTable
```

EDIT : Ok, i am making this edit because according to your comment, there are two issues we need to address. (I am leaving the original answer as it is in case it might help somebody.)

1) Result set should be filtered and there should be no `else` part.

This is actually achievable with this solution since `else` is optional and data can be filtered with a where clause at the end.

2) Being able to select the same row multiple times with different `Testing #` values if it matches the criteria.

This however is not achievable with my previous solution. So i thought of a different one. Hope it fits into your case. Here it is

S1 - Create a new table with `Testing #` values(`Testing #1`, `Testing #2`, `Testing #3` etc.). Let's say this table is named `Testing`.

S2 - JOIN your main table (`MyTable`) with `Testing` table which contains `Testing #` values. So now you have every possible combination of real-data and testing values.

S3 - Filter the results you don't want to appear with a where clause.

S4 - Filter the real-data <-> testing combinations with an addition to where clause.

End query should look something like this :

```
SELECT M.Column1, T.TestingValue
FROM MyTable M
INNER JOIN Testing T ON 1=1
WHERE 
(
    (M.Column2 IS NOT NULL AND M.Column3='Value' AND T.TestingValue='Testing #1') OR
    (M.Column3 IS NULL AND M.Column2='Test Value' AND T.TestingValue='Testing #2') OR
    <conditions for other testing values>
)
AND
<other conditions>
```

I think this should work and produce the results you want. But since i don't have the data   i am not able to run any benchmarks vs the union-based solution. So i don't have any scientific evidence to claim this is faster but it is an option. You can test both and use the better one.

It might be a little late but hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for providing a nice suggestion. I found several problems with this solution though. 1. There's no 'Testing #3'. I mean this query returns all records from MyTable, but I only need rows that match the criteria, there should be no "else". 2. There's no way to select the same row twice. Let's say that my row fits multiple conditions, then I want to select it multiple times only with different 'Testing #' label, but current solution will only select first match

Comment: @user194076: so create multiple columns, each with a case statement. Beyond that there is no magic solution

Comment: @MitchWheat, ok. Generally speaking, do you know which one would perform better? The one that will create multiple columns and then merge them into one column, or the solution with UNION ALL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one statement, but you want a different column for each test:

```
select column1,
       (case when column2 is not null and column3 = 'Value' then 1 else 0
        end) as Test1
       (case when column3 is null and column3 = 'Test Value' then 1 else 0
        end) as Test2,
       . . .
from t;
```

Because you only want cases where things fail, you can put this in a subquery and test for any failure:

```
select *
from (select column1,
             (case when column2 is not null and column3 = 'Value' then 1 else 0
              end) as Test1
             (case when column3 is null and column3 = 'Test Value' then 1 else 0
              end) as Test2,
             . . .
      from t
     ) t
where test1 + test2 + . . . > 0
```

Comment: Thank you for a code, but it doesn't work as expected. I do not need to select multiple columns. I just need to have one column with different labels ('Testing #1', 'Testing #2', etc..) based on the condition met. One row can meet multiple conditions.

Comment: @user194076 . . . If you want to understand the underlying logic, I suggest that you look at all the conditions independently.  In any case, frkn's solution puts everything into one column.